# How to enable GKE's network policy via deployment manager template?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm creating a GKE cluster via deployment manager and I'm using a template like so:

```
resources:
- name: cluster
  type: gcp-types/container-v1:projects.locations.clusters
  properties:
    cluster:
      name: my-cluster
      ...
      nodePools:
      - name: default
        ...
      addonsConfig:
        networkPolicyConfig:
          disabled: false
```

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters#networkpolicyconfig

The cluster created successfully but on the cluster page in the GCP console "Network Policy" shown to be disabled.

What's the correct way to enable it?

EDIT: Actually, it says "Network policy is immutable when dataplane V2 is enabled." but according to the documentation Network Policy is enabled by default for Dataplane v2, so I guess it's enabled after all?

EDIT 2: I tested and confirmed that network policies are NOT enforced

Comment: Dataplane V2 (DPv2) has built-in support for NetworkPolicy so enabling the network policy at the cluster level is a no-op.  If you do not have DPv2 enabled, then the you need to enable network policy for your cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know how I missed that but there's actually [networkPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters#Cluster.NetworkPolicy) property with the option to enable it. When I set it I see that now "Network Policy" shown as Enabled in the console. However, now Dataplane v2 is shown disabled, I guess this means it switches to Calico CNI. Makes no sense to me, since Dataplane v2 supposed to have network policy enabled, I don't mind using it.